# Get error when i display a map to wordpress using leaflet tool (Uncaught Error: Map container not found)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, leaflet

I am trying to insert the leaflet javascript to display a map from mapserver, i tried this following code but i got this error :

```
Uncaught Error: Map container not found.
    at e._initContainer (leaflet.js?ver=1:6)
    at e.initialize (leaflet.js?ver=1:6)
    at new e (leaflet.js?ver=1:6)
    at Object.o.map (leaflet.js?ver=1:6)
    at script1.js?ver=1:3
```

I did search some tutorials but i didn't found something for wordpress, so i don't know what i do to solve this problem.
This is the code i use to insert the js and css leaflet files in `functions.php`:

```
function add_js_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('script-leaflet-js', 'http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js',array() ,true);
wp_enqueue_style( 'script-leaflet-css','http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css',array(),true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-leaflet-map', get_template_directory_uri().'/script1.js', array(), true );}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js_scripts');
```

script1.js :

```
        var map = L.map('mapid').setView([29, -6.8644], 5); 
L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:81/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/wamp64/www/wordpress/map1.map", {
            layers: 'map1',
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: true,
            attribution: "Dan's Amazing Roads",
            maxZoom: 18,
            minZoom: 12,
        }).addTo(mapid);
```

and this is the code i insert in the page :

```
<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using jquery ? Ensure your script is called when dom is ready !

Comment: @MTroy No I am not using Jquery... How can I be sure that the script is called when dom is ready? because the codes are scattered :/

Comment: answered, try it in place of your current script1 content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Try to load when DOM is ready

Since the `$in_footer` argument of `wp_enqueue_script()` is true. 
It gets enqueued in the `wp_footer()` action, usually right before the ending of the body tag, and will be read in last then called when dom beeing ready.

Doc: [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

```
(function()
{
   var map = L.map('mapid').setView([29, -6.8644], 5); 
   L.tileLayer.wms("htt....
})();
```

Another method, all browsers (except old IE...)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
   var map = L.map('mapid').setView([29, -6.8644], 5); 
   L.tileLayer.wms("htt....

}, false);
```

Comment: @ghybs: Yes, because the last argument of `wp_enqueue_script()` is true. It gets enqueued in the `wp_footer()` action, usually right before the ending of the body tag, and will be read in last then called when dom beeing ready !

Comment: @MTroy still, what is the point of wrapping in an IIFE in this case?